# Django 1.8 migrate: django_content_type does not exist

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.7, django-migrations, django-1.8

I just upgraded my django from 1.7.1 to 1.8.4. I tried to run `python manage.py migrate` but I got this error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist`

I dropped my database, created a new one, and ran the command again. But I get the same error. Am I missing something? Do I need to do something for upgrading my django?

EDIT:
I downgraded back to 1.7.1 and it works. Is there a way to fix it for 1.8.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the issue. I have `auditlog` installed as one my apps. I removed it and migrate works fine.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this problem in detail? I'm facing the exact same problem as u, but have no idea what the `auditlog` means here. Thank a lot!

Comment: @JasonZhu `auditlog` is an external django app that was installed in my project. I cannot recall why it messed up the migration, but after I removed it from my settings, the migrations worked again. Have this in mind that my problem was solved because of a specific django app, so your project could be a whole different story.

Comment: OK! thanks for ur reply anyway, finally I found that my problem is related with postgres database privilege for user : )

Answer (score 6):

Delete all the migration folder from your app and delete the database then migrate your database......

if this does not work delete django_migration table from database and add the "name" column in django_content_type table `ALTER TABLE django_content_type ADD COLUMN name character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'anyName';` and then run `$ python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found/did. I am using django 1.8.13 and python 2.7. The problem did not occur for Sqlite. It did occur for PostgreSQL.

I have an app the uses a GenericForeignKey (which relies on Contenttypes). I have another app that has a model that is linked to the first app via the GenericForeignKey. If I run makemigrations for both these apps, then migrate works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to migrate our models from scratch (especially when testing builds). Upon further investigation, it turned out that we have custom codes related to `ContentTypes` model which is associated with the `django_content_type` table:

```
staff_content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(model__in=ACCOUNT_STAFF_APPS)
```

Then, in our succeeding codes that will access the `staff_content_types` variable, it will throw the `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'django_content_type' doesn't exist` message. Apparently, it tries to access the `django_content_type` table which is yet to be built. And our code are based in the context that our data are already setup.

So, there are at least 2 workarounds possible. The idea is to run our custom ContentType-related logic only when our site has already data (after the migration phase):

1. Catch the error which happens during migration and ignore it:

   ```
   from django.db.utils import ProgrammingError

   try:
       for content_type in staff_content_types:
           # Our custom codes here.
   except ProgrammingError:
       pass
   ```
2. Proceed only if `django_content_type` table exists (which is the state after migration):

   ```
   from django.db import connection

   if 'django_content_type' in connection.introspection.table_names():
       for content_type in staff_content_types:
           # Our custom codes here.
   ```

Likewise, 3rd-party apps that utilize the Django `ContentType` objects/table might have similar issues. So, either you disable them or requests their authors to patch their contrib apps w/ the ideas suggested here.

Comment: This is superb solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i had drop the database and rebuild it, then in the PyCharm Terminal `py manage.py makemigrations` and `py manage.py migrate` fix this problem. I think the reason is the table django_content_type is the django's table, if it misssed can not migrate, so have to drop the database and rebuild.

Comment: > drop the database :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate `contenttypes` first, then the rest of the the models included with Django, then your own models:

```sh
./manage.py migrate contenttypes
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py makemigrations <YOUR APP>
./manage.py migrate --fake
```